# How to inject templates when using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Following this tutorial:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

I have three files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .navbar { border-radius:0; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app="routerApp">

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
    <div ui-view></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
```

partial-home.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>    
</div>
```

This should, according to the tutorial, render the following:

[image: Expected result]

But i only get the header, the partial-home template is never injected.

Where do I go wrong? Has something changed since the tutorial was published?

Comment: Did you check for any JS error on console?

Comment: what does your folder structure look like? the templateUrl property is relative to app.js

Comment: Try `templateUrl: '/partial-home.html'`.  The `templateUrl` path will begin with the root of the application.  Double check that `partial-home.html` is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops...

Turns out I didn't run my app from a webserver. I just opened the file in a browser and that's why it didn't work.

Everything works fine when the app ran on the server =)

Answer (score 2):

I made one [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6blPzWoHxSur3meHBbGi?p=preview) and it is working fine.

```
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .navbar { border-radius:0; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Just check the files and path.